# WinForms UserControl image resource

Tags: winforms, image, user-controls, resources

I am developing a user control and want to save an image as a part of that control. I added the image to the control resource, but I can not access the image using code (like `Properties.Resources`.etc) Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

In the Resource Editor one needs to select in the Access Modifiers drop-down list something other than No Code Generation.